# PHP Video Surfer using iframe and an array list

Tags: php, arrays, list, iframe, video

How i can get this php code to work? I need to make a video iframe surfer using an array list

```
<?php
    $videos = array("UT163ZOeKz0" , "ur47gqA1CQo" , "UPEeggt2qAo" , "6lO07NjTsrM"); 
    $list = array_search($videos);
    $id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : $list;

    echo "<iframe width='375' height='310' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/".$videos[$id]."?&amp;fmt=22&amp;autoplay=1'> </iframe>";

    $next = isset($videos[($id+1)]) ? ($id+1) : 0;
    $prev = isset($videos[($id-1)]) ? ($id-1) : count($videos)-1;
?> 

<a href="video.php?id=<?php echo $prev; ?>">Previous video</a> | <a href="video.php?id=<?php echo $next; ?>">Next video</a>
```

How can i get the videos displayed in order according to the array list?

What can i do?

I will appreciate your answers.

Comment: `foreach` is not a command. Learn PHP from basics first, especially looping.

Comment: hi how can i edit my php code to display the videos in order according to the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use a temporary storage, like sessions with this. Just save which current index you are right now, and use that to the `$videos` index. Example:

```
session_start();
$videos = array("UT163ZOeKz0" , "ur47gqA1CQo" , "UPEeggt2qAo" , "6lO07NjTsrM");
$size = count($videos) - 1;
// simple initialization
$_SESSION['current'] = !isset($_SESSION['current']) ? 0 : $_SESSION['current']; 

if(isset($_GET['next'])) { // if chosen next
    // if out of bouds, reset to the first, else shift to next key
    $_SESSION['current'] = ($_SESSION['current'] >= $size) ? 0 : $_SESSION['current']+1;
} 

if(isset($_GET['prev'])) { // if chosen prev
    // if out of bounds show the last, else shift to previous key
    $_SESSION['current'] = ($_SESSION['current'] > 0) ? $_SESSION['current']-1 : $size;
}

$video = $videos[$_SESSION['current']]; // assign the current key
?>

<iframe width='375' height='310' src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $video; ?>?&fmt=22&autoplay=1"></iframe><br/>
<a href="index.php?prev">Previous video</a> | <a href="index.php?next">Next video</a>
```

Comment: @user3796104 sure no prob!